# MonoDevelop can't import VS2017 solutions

Tags: linux, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, monodevelop

I run Linux (Elementary) on my machine and for .NET MVC projects, I use Monodevelop ( 5.4.0.199 version), but I cannot open projects developed using Visual Studio 2017.

Opening the `.sln` file, the following error will keep appearing: `Error while trying to load the project '/home/emma/Documents/My-App/My-App/My-App.csproj': Unknown ToolsVersion '15.0'`.
I tried to update the monodevelop version, but with no success. I, also, tried to do what is suggested here: [MonoDevelop can't import VS2013/2015 solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093212/monodevelop-cant-import-vs2013-2015-solutions) , but, with no success.

Can you, please, help me solving this issue?

Comment: Just change the first couple of lines of the solution to a 2015 format file.  Most of the option will work.

Comment: You should upgrade to MonoDevelop 7+ as stated on documentation of build requirements from version 7 it is required to have vs2017
https://github.com/mono/md-website/commit/55cc783d41e6a0ada48595f78907c194d25e269e#diff-8afa99fec9034401d89cfbf1609997aa
So, probably compatibility to 2017 is only available from v7 on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Update MonoDevelop to a version superior to 7
2. Change ToolsVersion from 15.0 to 14.0 or smaller based on which version of VS is supported by your version of MonoDevelop*

*To check which version of VS is supported for each MonoDevelop version check the history of MonoDevelop requirements [Here](https://github.com/mono/md-website/commits/gh-pages/developers/building-monodevelop.md))

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The second solution worked for me.